# Scrapy extracting from javascript element

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extract data from the following url by using scrapy.

```
import re
import json    
import scrapy    
import unicodedata    
from collections import Counter

#command scrapy crawl <spidername> -o <outputfile>

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "ljcmnt"    
    start_urls = ['https://asperger.livejournal.com/3084959.html']    
    def parse(self, response):    
        comments_ids = response.xpath("//*[@id='comments']/div[5]/div/@data-tid").extract()   
        print comments_ids
```

But since the element(`data-tid`) in java script I am not able to catch it.

Any help in getting the `data-tid` from the `start-url`.

Comment: find tag `<script>`, get all as normal text and use standard string functions or regex to find element in text.

Comment: or maybe you means this element is added by javascript ? Scrapy doesn't run JavaScipt amd you need `Selenium` to control web browser which will run JavaScript. But JavaScript may load this data from some url and you could find this url using DevTools in Chrome/Firefox. And then you can read it driectly from this url.